# dynamic table name in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating dynamic tables in mysql database using the following code which works fine.

however, I want to create a second table as well based on the dynamic table name!

for example:

the `dynamic table name` is : `David`
the `second table based on David table` should be: `David.books` or `David-books`

**here is my current code:**

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare( $db_conx, "CREATE TABLE  $user (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)"
);
```

**I tried this and didn't create the table:**

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare( $db_conx, "CREATE TABLE  $user.'books' (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)"
);
```

**I also tried it like this and it did not create any tables:**

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare( $db_conx, "CREATE TABLE  $user.books (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)"
);
```

could someone please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Neither `David.books` nor `David-books` is a good identifier name, because [you've got to quote them](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html). Why not `David_books` instead?

Comment: put your table names between `

Comment: Any errors or messages?

Comment: The answers are rolling in like oranges vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

Comment: Table names created dynamically like this as usually a sign of bad design. Why not a **SINGLE** books table, and then an `ownername` field where you'd put "David".

Comment: @Fred-ii- don't you just love that :D

Comment: Yeah, feel the love ;-) @user3592614

Comment: @MarcB, no, I cannot do that in this project because each user has his/her own subdomain and each subdomain has many different tables in mysql database and I am trying to keep away from too many join tables etc...

Comment: "from too many joins" tables? so you create **MORE** tables?

Comment: @MarcB, yeah because the users will not stay on the same subdomain for long. they only have 30 days to use it and then their subdomain will expire and their mysql table will be deleted. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't single-quote around your table name:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare( $db_conx, "CREATE TABLE " .$user. "_books (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)"
);
```

Also, [don't use a dot in a table name.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776123/mysql-dot-in-database-name).

Also, per @Fred-ii-, [don't use a dash in your table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670394/using-dash-in-mysql-table-name).

Comment: Curious: Why the hyphen in `-books`? Hyphens shouldn't be used in SQL as it may be misinterpreted as a minus sign, unless backticked.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ahh, it was the questioner's alternate to a dot, and I didn't even think about that. Fixed.

Comment: It seems that the OP has quite a choice of answers to pick from lol

Comment: I used `_books` and it worked just fine so accepting this answer.

Comment: It paid off eh? @DigitalChris ;-) +1

Comment: @Fred-ii- my answers have that certain *je ne sais quoi*. Also I was first :p

Comment: @DigitalChris *Je le sais, je le sais* ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have dots in mySQL table names, with unquoted identifiers.

```
Database and table names cannot contain '/', '\', '.', or characters
that are not permitted in file names.
```

ref : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Moreover, your use of tables seems unorthodox and you should use the possibilities offered by RELATIONAL databases.

Such as : [Database schema for Books, Authors, Publishers and Users with bookshelves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159333/database-schema-for-books-authors-publishers-and-users-with-their-bookshelfs)

Comment: You can have [dots in MySQL table names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifier-mapping.html) now, but I wouldn't recommend the use of dots.

Answer (score 0):

$stmt = mysqli_prepare( $db_conx, "CREATE TABLE  ".$user."-books (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)"
);

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of putting strings together is using a . like you did, but you did not define the dot that you want in the string itself:

```
$string = $user . ".books"; // This will return "David.books"
$string = $user . "-books"; // And this will return "David-books"
```

You see how I added an additional dot?

Perhaps you could even do something like `$string = $user.".books";` and then doing

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_conx, "CREATE TABLE $string");
```

Because I don't think it MySQL allows you to put strings together like the way you did

Answer (score 0):

you cant write $user as-is. you have to do like this: "CREATE TABLE '".$user.".books' ( id in(11) ....  hope it helps